# Change navigation bar color in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, ios11

I want to change navigation bar color of QLPreviewController in swift 3. I have used below code to change color but its not working

```
viewQLPreview = QLPreviewController()
viewQLPreview.dataSource = self
viewQLPreview.delegate = self
viewQLPreview.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
viewQLPreview.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: Try this if works out for you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239664/how-to-customize-the-color-of-the-navigation-bar-in-qlpreviewcontroller

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64154848/1836420

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used below code to Change navigation bar color of QLPreviewController in swift 3.0

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red

UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: QLPreviewController is not found when I do this. UIKit is imported in the file. Any idea what to import in order to use QLPreviewController?

Comment: QLPreviewController lives in QuickLook:
`import QuickLook`

Answer (score 4):

Use below code before present QLPreviewController :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(fromColor(color: UIColor.blue), for: .default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false 

func fromColor (color: UIColor) -> UIImage{
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)
        let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image ?? UIImage()
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

Put below code in viewDidLoad of `QLPreviewController`.

```
viewQLPreview.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
viewQLPreview.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Also make sure that `viewQLPreview.navigationController != nil`

If you are pushing `QLPreviewController` then this code will work....

If you are presenting `QLPreviewController` then you need to make sure that rootController should be navigation controller, in your case..

```
let viewQLPreview = QLPreviewController()
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewQLPreview)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer using your code i can able to change color but cancel button not appeat in navigation bar.

Comment: just set the tintColor and barTintColor of navigation bar.:)

Comment: This is perfect answer for me, thanks for explaining